# Referring to a current type using Java generics

Tags: java, generics

I have an interface with a type parameter that allows its conversion into the same type with another type parameter. Like this:

```
interface Interfaze<A> {
    public <B> Interfaze<B> convert(java.util.function.Function<A, B> f);
}
```

I now want to impose a stricter requirement on the return type: I want the `convert` method to only return the same type as it was called on. Like this:

```
class GoodInterfaze<A> implements Interfaze<A> {
    public <B> Interfaze<B> convert(java.util.function.Function<A, B> f) {
        // return new GoodInterfaze<B>();     // I want this to be allowed by compiler
        // return new BadInterfaze<B>();      // I want this to be a compilation error

        return null;
    }
}

class BadInterfaze<A> implements Interfaze<A> {
    public <B> Interfaze<B> convert(java.util.function.Function<A, B> f) {
        // return new GoodInterfaze<B>();     // I want this to be a compilation error
        // return new BadInterfaze<B>();      // I want this to be allowed by compiler

        return null;
    }
}
```

The `Interfaze` interface is under my control, so I can add extra type parameters to it (or its methods) when needed. Do Java generics allow for anything like this?

Comment: a question: What is the point of having <A>? and not using it anywhere?.. and an answer: No. and finally a suggestion, contact Angelika Langer

Comment: @Hector: man, that's a deliberately simplified example, but I've updated it for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get close by doing this.

```
public interface Interfaze<T extends Interfaze<T>> {

    T convert();
}
```

Then you can do

```
public class Main {

    public static class Good implements Interfaze<Good> {

        @Override
        public Good convert() { return new Good(); } // Compiles
    }

    public static class Bad implements Interfaze<Bad> {

        @Override
        public Bad convert() { return new Good(); } // Doesn't compile
    }
}
```

This idea of using recursive bounds like this is very common. I personally dislike it as it's very confusing and because it doesn't mix well with inheritance. For example, you can't make a subclass `SubGood` of `Good` that implements `Interfaze<SubGood>` because you can't implement the same generic interface with 2 different type arguments. It only really works if all implementing classes cannot be extended (that's why `Enum<E extends Enum<E>>` is ok).

Comment: It will work the exact same way if declared as `public interface Interface<T>`. The recursive bound is useless in your code as written.

Comment: @newacct I agree I haven't explained this particularly well. It's not quite the same. At least in my version you are prevented from writing `class Foo implements Interface<String>`. What we really want is to be able to refer to "this type", but sadly that's not possible.

Comment: But there is no type-safety reason to prevent someone from writing `class Foo implements Interface<String>` if they wanted to, as long as it's type-safe. A bound is only meaningful to *allow* you to do something safely you can't do before.